# A heuristic for finding an edge cycle cover

Tags: graphs, approximation, complexity-classes, heuristics

I am looking to find a minimum list of cycles in a graph such that their union gives the list of all simple cycles in this graph.

In the example below, here are 4 simple undirected cycles: 1-2-3, 2-3-4, 1-3-4-5 and 1-2-3-4-5. The last cycle does not add any further information about the cyclic structure of my graph that's why I don not want to process it.

[image: Example]

I made few searches and found out there is the Edge Cycle Cover and finding the minimum is NP-HARD problem. I'm not sure if it is exactly what I'm looking for.

So, any help understanding this problem? Is there a heuristic to get only a subset of cycles for each vertex in the graph? it does not have to be minimal!

Comment: what is the condition for disregarding a cycle? You say the cover has not be minimal but it looks like you disregard cycle 1-2-3-4-5 because 1-3-4-5 and 1-2-3 (being both shorter!) provide the same information when considered together. Also, it does not seem to me you are looking for cycles, but *transpositions* (i.e., different paths between two different nodes), ...

Comment: @CarlosLinaresLópez actually I would love to get the minimal cover, but as you said in my intuition I am thinking about shorter cycles. Maybe, I didn't formulate my question properly, but I am simply looking for a way to not process all the cycles in the graph because some cycles do not give more information about the graph structure, i.e. that are composed of edges already in previously processed cycles. So maybe looking for a cycle containing every edge in the graph would do the job?

Comment: So do you want a small number of cycles that covers every edge? How does your problem differ?

Comment: @Juho That's what I want yup! It is the same as Minimum cover problem right?

Comment: @Juho What I'm doing now is coloring my edges and checking for every non visited edge (not already part of previously found cycle/ colored gray) if it is part of a cycle. It will not give me the minimum cover but I find it simple and yet efficient way to get a cycle cover.

Comment: How large are your graphs? How many cycles might they roughly have? How much time do you have for finding a single cover, i.e., how fast should the heuristic be?

Comment: My graphs are small in practice (|V|<100 and |E|<100). I'm handling the general case so there might be no limit for the number of existing cycles. Polynomial time is considered fast in my case! The approach I described in my previous comment returns a list of cycles in O((|V|+|E|)×|E|) time ! Now, I'm wondering if it's possible to optimize it further? Knowing that, to get the cycle containing edge (u,v), I'm using BFS  on E\{(u, v)} to get the shortest path from v to u if it exists (O(|u|+|v|))! the same work repeated for all edges in the  worst case which gives O( (|V|+|E|)×|E|)